# Como utilizar tipos genéricos com parâmetros de tipos?

Tags: c#, reflexão, genéricos

Eu tenho um dicionário que serve como um mapeador de tipos com C#.

```
var Map = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
{
    {typeof(A1), typeof(A2)},
    {typeof(B1), typeof(B2)},
    {typeof(C1), typeof(C2)},
    {typeof(D1), typeof(D2)}
};
```

pretendo usá-lo da seguinte maneira:

```
public virtual T Get<T>(int id) where T : CD.IDomainModel
{
    using (var rep = new R.Rep())
    {
        var t = PegarEquavalencia(typeof(T));

        var obj = rep.Get<t>(id);//Aqui aponta um erro no 't'

        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), obj);
    }
}

public static Type PegarEquavalencia(Type type)
{
    Type tipoEquivalente;
    Map.TryGetValue(type, out tipoEquivalente);

    return tipoEquivalente;
}
```

O problema é que não consegui ainda utilizar este Map de tipos para poder fazer esta ação.
Basicamente o que eu quero fazer é passar um tipo A1, pegar o equivalente dele no dicionário, no caso A2, e usar o tipo do A2 como parâmetro para o tipo genérico do outro método.

Estou usando o NHibernate, e a classe Rep é um repositório genérico. O método `Get<T>(object id)` é possui o tipo genérico para retornar o objeto que desejo pegar no banco.

Minha solução possui, basicamente, 3 projetos:

- Um para o mapeamento da base de dados, Domain, Mapping (xml) e Repository;
- Um para UI;
- E o outro para a lógica de negócios da aplicação.

No projeto que encapsula a lógica de negócios, eu possuo objetos que serão usados para troca de dados com a UI.

Fiz um dicionário como dito acima para mapear os objetos para comunicação da UI com os objetos do Mapeamento com o ORM.

O que eu pretendo fazer é pedir um objeto do tipo A1, da interface, aí um método intermediário irá verificar seu equivalente no dicionário, pesquisará o objeto com o tipo equivalente, A2, na base de dados, e retornará o objeto A1 que recebe com parâmetro o objeto A2;

Comment: Não entendi. Pra que serve o parâmetro `Id`?

Comment: O @CiganoMorrisonMendez está certo:" Para que o `Id`?" Poderia por um código de exemplo que funcione?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível fazer isso via reflexão.

Para chamar o método usando reflexão, dado um tipo `t` obtido a partir do dicionário:

```
public virtual T Get<T>(int id) where T : CD.IDomainModel
{
    using(var rep = new Rep())
    {
        var t = PegarEquavalencia(typeof(T));

        // chamando o método via reflexão... isso não é muito eficiente,
        // mas no caso citado, de acesso a banco de dados, talvez seja aceitável
        var obj = typeof(Rep)
            .GetMethod("Get", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .MakeGenericMethod(t)
            .Invoke(rep, new object[] { id });

        Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), obj);
    }
}
```

Note que isso é ineficiente, então o recomendável é criar um delegate para fazer a ação desejada, por completo, e usar um dicionário de tipos para delegates da ação pretendida.

Vou postar um exemplo de como fazer da forma mais eficiente... enquanto isso pode usar tentar da forma indicada, que vai dar certo!

**Exemplo compilando o delegate na hora, e armazenando em cache**

Esse exemplo é para o caso de você precisar de mais performance, caso um dia a reflexão comece a pesar no processamento... digo isso, pois o código é mais complicado, e você vai precisar de uma boa desculpa para utilizar esse monstro:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> cache
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();

public virtual T Get<T>(int id) where T : CD.IDomainModel
{
    var t2 = PegarEquavalencia(typeof(T));
    var getInternal = (Func<int, T>)cache
        .GetOrAdd(typeof(T), t => DelegateFor_GetInternal<T>(t2));
    var result = getInternal(id);
    return result;
}

private static Func<int, T> DelegateFor_GetInternal<T>(Type t2)
{
    var ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new[] { t2 });

    var param = Expression.Parameter(t2, "obj");

    var creatorType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(t2, typeof(T));

    dynamic lambda = typeof(Class2)
        .GetMethod("Lambda", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .MakeGenericMethod(creatorType)
        .Invoke(null, new object[]
        {
            Expression.New(ctor, param), new[] { param }
        });

    var creatorDelegate = (object)lambda.Compile();

    // func
    var getInternal = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GetInternal<,>)
        .MakeGenericType(t2, typeof(T)), creatorDelegate);

    var result = (Func<int, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(Func<int, T>),
        getInternal,
        getInternal.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke",
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance));

    return result;
}

private static Expression<TDelegate> Lambda<TDelegate>(
    Expression body, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(body, parameters);
}

public class GetInternal<T2, T>
{
    private readonly Func<T2, T> creator;

    public GetInternal(Func<T2, T> creator)
    {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public T Invoke(int id)
    {
        using (var rep = new R.Rep())
        {
            var obj = rep.Get<T2>(id);
            return creator(obj);
        }
    }
}

public static Type PegarEquavalencia(Type type)
{
    Type tipoEquivalente;
    Map.TryGetValue(type, out tipoEquivalente);

    return tipoEquivalente;
}
```

Comment: Então, editei o post e coloquei mais detalhes sobre a minha dúvida. Referente ao que você falou sobre matar a utilidade das classes genéricas, é justamente isto que eu não quero fazer, pois por enquanto estou trabalhando com 29 tabelas, e 29 classes equivalentes, e com uma grande previsão de aumento. Se tiver que fazer algo específico para cada uma ai vai ser muito trabalhoso.