# Para que serve a declaração Box<T>?

Tags: tipagem, genéricos, hack, hhvm

Eu estava dando uma olhada na [documentação do Hack](http://hacklang.org/).

Sei que essa linguagem é uma modificação do PHP para introduzir a verificação de tipos.

Vi que eles colocam esse exemplo para demonstrar o uso de classes, acho que tem a ver com definição de tipos primitivos.

```
class Box<T> {
  protected T $data;

  public function __construct(T $data) {
    $this->data = $data;
  }

  public function getData(): T {
    return $this->data;
  }
}
```

Estou acostumado com as classes do PHP e nunca tinha visto até então uma declaração como essa.

Parece que ele só aceita somente a letra `T`, pois fiz uns testes aqui na minha máquina com outros nomes, porém gerou erros.

Afinal, o que significa essa declaração `Box<T>`?

Comment: Você quer saber sobre o `Box` ou o `<T>` em geral?

Comment: O `<T>`. O `Box` eu já sei que é uma classe :´

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é sobre [programação genérica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101), fundamental em linguagens estaticamente tipadas. Por isso tem em Hack e não no PHP.

Ali o `T` funciona como uma super variável e terá um valor substituído mais tarde - esse valor só pode ser um tipo de dado. Quando você for instanciar essa classe terá que informar sobre que tipo de dados a instância trabalhará, afinal em linguagem estaticamente tipada todos os dados precisam de um tipo fixo. Essa classe pode encaixotar dados de qualquer tipo. Imagine a loucura que seria criar uma classe nova para cada tipo que precise.

Em uma linguagem dinâmica é mais simples porque ela cria uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e trata os dados de forma genérica e resolve em tempo de execução, podendo dar certo ou não. Em linguagem estática precisa resolver em tempo de compilação dando mais segurança e performance.

É uma forma de instruir o compilador para usar essa classe em uma implementação especial em cada instanciação. Então o compilador gerará por conta própria uma nova versão da classe para cada tipo efetivamente instanciado na sua aplicação. Todos os lugares onde tem um `T` receberá o tipo a ser instanciado.

Se instanciar com um `int` (ex.: `new Box<int>`) a classe interna gerada (você não precisa saber sobre isto) será algo assim:

```
class BoxInt {
    protected int $data;

    public function __construct(int $data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getData(): int {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/GenericsHack.hh).

Pode usar o identificador que quiser ali, até porque pode ter vários em classes que dependem de mais de um tipo. Mas precisa ter coerência do seu uso em toda classe. O erro pode ser porque falou mudar em outros lugares onde ainda tinha o `T`, mas não sei, isso não foi postado, só posso responder especulando.

Answer (score 0):

Em c# essa notação serve para você poder instanciar a mesma classe, mas modificar os tipos . É uma declaração de tipo genérica. Por exemplo...

```
new Box<string>();
```

e

```
new Box<int>();
```

Geram o objeto tipo Box para internamente $data será `string` no primeiro caso e `int` no segundo.