# Como não repetir o mesmo código em uma sobrecarga?

Tags: .net, vb.net, genéricos, sobrecarga

Qual seria técnica correta para não repetir o mesmo código para estas duas sobrecargas ou talvez não ter as sobrecargas?

Ocorre que por vezes tenho que passar um parâmetro que é um vetor de strings e outras vezes passo vetor de inteiros. Se eu não *tipar* os parâmetros, não funciona, pois o compilador reclama que não pode converter inteiro para objeto.

```
 Private Sub CarregarArraysPeloDgv(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, ByRef a() As String)

        ' REDIMENSIONAR
        If a Is Nothing Then
            ReDim a(dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If dgv.Rows.Count > a.Count Then
            ReDim a(dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
        End If

        ' ALIMENTAR
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
            a(x) = Val(row.Cells(0).Value)
            x = x + 1
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub CarregarArraysPeloDgv(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, ByRef a() As Integer)
        ' REDIMENSIONAR
        If a Is Nothing Then
            ReDim a(dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If dgv.Rows.Count > a.Count Then
            ReDim a(dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
        End If

        ' ALIMENTAR
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
            a(x) = Val(row.Cells(0).Value)
            x = x + 1
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Todo tipo deriva de 'object' em .Net, não tem como castar o int pra obj?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso você deve usar [*generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) e não sobrecarga, então precisa parametrizar o tipo, aí quando for chamar diz qual o tipo que usará. Não sei se em VB.NET tem inferência, em C# eu sei que é comum não precisar indicar de forma explícita. Em alguns casos a genericidade deve estar na classe e só parametrizar no método, aí tem que ver todo o contexto para decidir se é melhor habilitar só para o método ou para a classe toda.

Toda vez que usar um *cast* morre um panda na China.

```
Private Sub CarregarArraysPeloDgv(Of T)(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, ByRef a() As T)
    ' REDIMENSIONAR
    If a Is Nothing Then
        ReDim a(dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If dgv.Rows.Count > a.Count Then
        ReDim a(dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
    End If

    ' ALIMENTAR
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        a(x) = Val(row.Cells(0).Value)
        x = x + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Generics.vb).

Comment: Nossa. Muito bom! Valeu mesmo!

Comment: @Tito veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.