# Por que usamos "<>" em TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tipagem, genéricos

Por que usamos `<>` em TypeScript? Exemplo:

```
funcaoExemplo(x: X<any>, x: X): Observable<X<any>>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isto é para indicar uma parametrização de tipos, também conhecido como [*generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) (alguns gostam de chamar de *diamond operator* mas ele não é um operador. Ele funciona como os parênteses de uma função, de fato é muito parecido já que os parênteses são usados para conter os parâmetros (ou [argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101), depende de onde está usando, em  algum momento o `<>` é usado como argumento genérico também). O que está ali dentro é justamente o tipo que pode usar, no caso `any` significa que pode usar qualquer um, neste caso é um argumento genérico já que está consumindo o tipo `x` que é genérico.

Ele lembra um pouco a ideia do *array* em linguagens de tipagem estática, sabe quando usa:

```
int[]
```

então, falando abstratamente, só para entender, não funciona assim, genericamente seria algo assim:

```
Array<int>
```

onde lê-se "um *array* de inteiros".

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/GenericSyntax.ts).

Em linguagens estaticamente tipadas você tem que dizer o tipo para tudo, incluindo o que vai dentro de um objeto. Não existe linguagem efetivamente estática sem *generics*, tem um remendo, mas quebra a tipagem.

Veja mais em [Diferença entre usar generics e "any" no TypeScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/466543/101).